# Angular2 + how set SkipLocationChange to true as default

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Want to set SkipLocationChange to true as default for my Angular2 app.
how?  For example, an app may have several calls to `router.navigate`

```
this.router.navigate(['/path', arg], {skipLocationChange:true})
```

Maybe there are 50 calls to router.navigate, which requires boilerplating this option `skipLocationChange:true` 50 times...

Comment: Ever figure this out per chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a guard that "modifies" the `extras` by rerunning the navigation:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SkipLocationChangeGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private readonly router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        // If skipLocationChange is true, allow to proceed
        const extras = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras;
        if (extras?.skipLocationChange) {
            return true;
        }

        // Otherwise, rerun the navigation with skipLocationChange on
        const url = this.router.parseUrl(state.url);
        this.router.navigateByUrl(url, {...extras, skipLocationChange: true});
        return false;
    }
}
```

And linking it to every route in your config, for example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'foo', component: FooComponent},
    {path: 'bar', component: BarComponent},
    {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/foo'},
];

/** Adds a guard to every non-redirect route. */
const addLocationGuard = (r: Route): Route => r.redirectTo ? r : {...r, canActivate: [SkipLocationChangeGuard]};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes.map(addLocationGuard)),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: [],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```